# How to fix this character in post method node js

Tags: node.js, api

When I use postman and post a array element its posting with some characters I don't know how to make it proper json

```
[{"name":"alpha","password":"123","id":4},"{\r\n      \"name\" : \"test\",\r\n      \"password\" : \"password3\",\r\n      \"id\": 5\r\n}\r\n"]
```

As in my above output

```
{"name":"alpha","password":"123","id":4}
```

This is my default value , when i post this

```
{\r\n      \"name\" : \"test\",\r\n      \"password\" : \"password3\",\r\n      \"id\": 5\r\n}\r\n"
```

I have some extra strings This my code

```
app.post("/postUser", function (req, res) {
    req.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
        fs.readFile("test.json", "utf8", function (readErr, fileData) {
            if (readErr) {
                console.error(readErr);
            }
            newData = JSON.parse(fileData);
            newData[newData.length] = data.toString();

            fs.writeFile("test.json", JSON.stringify(newData), "utf8", function (writeErr) {
                if (writeErr) {
                    console.error(writeErr);
                }
                console.log("Finished writing!");

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**data** is still a utf8 string, and so is including standard newline characters. You can add a body parser to your server to make life easier (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

```
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
 ...
 app.post("/postUser", (req, res) => {
     console.log(req.body);
 }
```

**EDIT**
You should also ensure requests are sent to the server with content-type application/json;

Comment: When you send the request to the server, are you specifying content-type as application/json?

Comment: It is not posting in that case

Comment: Did you set it by going to body, selecting 'raw' from the radio options, and then JSON application/json from the drop down that appears on the right?

Comment: yes i did but if it is in application/javascript it is posting in json file otherwise no response

Comment: When using application/json, do you get a response at all into postman?

Comment: can we use body parse

Comment: Can you upload a minimal version of your project, and I can take a quick look

Comment: I've added the application/json requirement to the answer since it's now working